# How do I set up a hotspot 802.11n with nmcli?

Tags: fedora, wifi-hotspot, nmcli

Almost everything is in the title ... I want to set up a Wi-Fi hotspot using only `nmcli` (no `hostapd` etc...) I'm doing this to create the hotspot (a small bash script):

```
#!/bin/sh
VAR_HOTSPOT="TEST"
nmcli con add type wifi ifname wlan0 con-name $VAR_HOTSPOT autoconnect yes ssid Hotspot-$VAR_HOTSPOT
nmcli con modify $VAR_HOTSPOT 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless.band bg ipv4.method shared
nmcli con modify $VAR_HOTSPOT 802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt wpa-psk
nmcli con modify $VAR_HOTSPOT 802-11-wireless-security.proto rsn
nmcli con modify $VAR_HOTSPOT 802-11-wireless-security.pairwise ccmp
nmcli con modify $VAR_HOTSPOT 802-11-wireless-security.group ccmp
nmcli con modify $VAR_HOTSPOT 802-11-wireless-security.psk "password"
nmcli con up $VAR_HOTSPOT
```

Every thing works fine except my connection is stuck at 65Mb/s.
My two PCs are 300Mb/s capable (2 USB WIFI HT20/HT40). How do I set warp speed ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use iw tools for this:

```
 iw wlp3s0 |grep -i mcast_rate
```

#### Example:

```
 iw dev wlan0 set mcast_rate 300000
```

#### Confirm changes with:

```
 iw wlan0 info
```

or

```
 nmcli connection show "Hotspot-$VAR_HOTSPOT"
```